# How do I save a mode 'F' image? (Python/PIL)

Tags: python, image

I have a ndarray with floats in it I want to save. I would like to keep the values as float though. The only format I found that accepts saving float data is tiff. Doesn't show the actual image however.

```
from Image import *
from numpy import *

img = random.random((300, 300)) #float numbers, i have actual data in my image though
img = fromarray(img)
img.save('test.tiff')
```

Comment: Can you describe the format of your image array? What's the range of your floats?

Comment: suppose [0, 1]. i don't see what difference it makes however. the random is generating numbers in that interval either way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example *is* saving a floating-point TIFF file. I've confirmed by examining the TIFF header, noting that the *samples per pixel* tag 0x153 has a value of 3 (floating point data). Using your example:

```
import Image
from numpy import *

data = random.random((2, 2))
img1 = Image.fromarray(data)
img1.save('test.tiff')
img2 = Image.open('test.tiff')

f1 = list(img1.getdata())
f2 = list(img2.getdata())
print f1 == f2
print f1
```

Output:

```
True
[0.27724304795265198, 0.12728925049304962, 0.4138914942741394, 0.57919681072235107]
```

[Details on the TIFF6 file format](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)

**Updated**: Example 64x64 image viewed on Mac desktop:
[image]

Comment: how come i can't get it to display the image correct in programs that open .tiff files? for example if open it on gimp all i see is an empty box.

Comment: Could be a limitation of Gimp. I'll update the answer to show you what I see in Mac's preview.

Comment: can you open the image with any free program? maybe i just have to use something else to open it then. i'll see if i find anything that works.

Comment: I don't know of a free program that will open floating point TIFFs, offhand, besides Mac's Preview.

Comment: I can affirm GIMP currently does not handle TIFF files with floating point pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

ImageJ opens float Tiff images.