# (Modify)Tensorflow tflearn Binary image learning questions

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-imaging-library, deep-learning

I would like to learn fingerprint images that have been binarized using PIL for the tensor flow.
I'm trying to learn a binarized image, so the shape is not right.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import pickle
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


def load_image(img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path)

    return img


def resize_image(in_image, new_width, new_height, out_image=None,
                 resize_mode=Image.ANTIALIAS):
    img = in_image.resize((new_width, new_height), resize_mode)

    if out_image:
        img.save(out_image)

    return img


def pil_to_nparray(pil_image):
    pil_image.load()

    return np.asarray(pil_image, dtype="float32")


def binarization(in_img, threshold):
    im = in_img.convert('L')
    for i in range(im.size[0]):
        for j in range(im.size[1]):
            if im.getpixel((i,j)) > threshold:
                im.putpixel((i,j), 255)
            else:
                im.putpixel((i,j), 0)
    return im.convert('F')


def load_data(datafile, num_clss, save=True, save_path='dataset.pkl'):
    train_list = open(datafile,'r')
    labels = []
    images = []
    for line in train_list:
        tmp = line.strip().split(' ')
        fpath = tmp[0]
        print(fpath)
        img = load_image(fpath)
        img = binarization(img, 128)
        img = resize_image(img, 224, 224)
        np_img = pil_to_nparray(img)
        images.append(np_img)

        index = int(tmp[1])
        label = np.zeros(num_clss)
        label[index] = 1
        labels.append(label)
    if save:
        pickle.dump((images, labels), open(save_path, 'wb'))

    return images, labels


def load_from_pkl(dataset_file):
    X, Y = pickle.load(open(dataset_file, 'rb'))
    return X, Y


def create_vggnet(num_classes):
    # Building 'VGGNet'
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 224, 224, 3], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 64, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 64, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
    network = conv_2d(network, 128, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 128, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 2, strides=2)

    network = conv_2d(network, 256, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, kernel_size=2, strides=2)

    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, kernel_size=2, strides=2)

    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 512, filter_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, kernel_size=2, strides=2)

    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='relu')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='relu')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, num_classes, activation='softmax')

    network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=0.001)

    return network


def train(network, X, Y):
    # Trainingeed data dictionary, with placeholders as keys, and data as values.
    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_vgg',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir='output')
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=100, validation_set=0.1, shuffle=True, show_metric=True,
              batch_size=64, snapshot_step=200, snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='vgg_fingerprint')
    model.save('model_save.model')


def predict(network, modelfile, images):
    model = tflearn.DNN(network)
    model.load(modelfile)

    return model.predict(images)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #image, label = load_data('train.txt', 5)
    X, Y = load_from_pkl('dataset.pkl')
    net = create_vggnet(5)
    train(net, X, Y)
```

I have tried using numpy reshape the dimensions change.
However, the following error is repeated.

The error is as follows.
ValueError: Can not feed value of shape (64,224,224) for Tensor u'input / X: 0 ', which has shape (?, 224, 224, 3)

What is the problem?

Comment: That's a large model and looks like it relies on pickled data. Could you try putting together a [minimal and complete example of the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your input shape - it doesn't match the input layer.

The input layer is defined in `create_vggnet()`:

```
def create_vggnet(num_classes):
    # Building 'VGGNet'
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 224, 224, 3], name='input')
```

So you expect `None` (== any) times (224, 224, 3), that is 224x224 x RGB (3 channels). And you pass 64 (your batch size) times 224x224.

There are two fixes:

1) (probably more wasteful) - extend the images to RGB.

So, after you convert the image to `'L'` (lightness, that is gray levels) and then binarize, convert it to RGB first. Then you can convert it to `'F'`

(See: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm and [How do I save a mode 'F' image? (Python/PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414586/how-do-i-save-a-mode-f-image-python-pil))

```
def binarization(in_img, threshold):
    im = in_img.convert('L')
    for i in range(im.size[0]):
        for j in range(im.size[1]):
            if im.getpixel((i, j)) > threshold:
                im.putpixel((i, j), 255)
            else:
                im.putpixel((i, j), 0)
    return im.convert('RGB').convert('F')
```

2) (less wasteful, but you're changing your network a bit (just the input layer) - so it can be argued, that this "isn't VGG 16 anymore") You can change the input layer to 1-channel.

```
def create_vggnet(num_classes):
    # Building 'VGGNet'
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 224, 224, 1], name='input')
```

Unfortunately, `shape=[None, 224, 224]` doesn't work (the error is something about "The Tensor needs to be 4D"). So we have a shape of (224, 224, 1) for a single input value.

So you need to make the images have an extra dimension:

```
def pil_to_nparray(pil_image):
    pil_image.load()

    return np.expand_dims(np.asarray(pil_image, dtype="float32"), 2)
```

or (maybe even better):

```
def pil_to_nparray(pil_image):
    pil_image.load()

    return np.asarray(pil_image, dtype="float32").reshape((224, 224, 1))
```

(the latter version looks more direct, you know exactly what it does)
But this only works if the input image is 224x224, while the `expand_dims` would always add the extra dimension, for any size.