# Python: What is the most efficient way to save/read a large number of float values in a compressed file

Tags: python, scipy, floating-point

I need to read the RGB values from an image file (e.g. `scipy.misc.imread`), process/convert them and store them as float values within the range (0.0 to 255.0) in a compressed file.

I have tried to use `numpy.savez_compressed` to save the float values into npz file and use `numpy.load` to read them back. However I found that `numpy.load` is taking a long time to read back the float values from the npz compressed file. If we use `scipy.misc.imsave` and `scipy.misc.imread`, it can save the RGB integer values in a compressed format, and read them very quickly. What is the most efficient way in terms of speed to read back the float values in a compressed file?

Comment: This question cannot be answered because efficiency (assuming you mean speed) depends on the type of compression and storage bandwith. Highly compressed data may be fast to read/write on the disk but slow to convert to/from RGB. In contrast, uncompressed data will be slow to read/write but very fast to convert. There is no single best approach - this highly depends on your application and data. You are going to have to try different approaches and select the one which works best for you.

Comment: High compression is not required as long as it is not storing the uncompressed raw data. Please can you suggest any approach that has low compression but enable fast reading?

Comment: Why do you want compression at all if you do not care how much it is compressed?

Comment: It is because I do not want to use up too much disk space. Some kind of compression on text files are good enough to reduce the disk space use.

Comment: So if you want *anything*, what's wrong with `imsave` and `imread`?

Comment: It is because `imsave` is unable to store the float values. I need to store the float values within the range (0.0 to 255.0) in a file and read it back later for further processing.

Comment: Oh, and I thought the question was about performance... See if [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414586/how-do-i-save-a-mode-f-image-python-pil) work for you.

Comment: Yes brilliant. We can save/read float values using the tiff image file type efficiently, and it provides a reasonable compression of the file. If you turn it to an answer I will mark it.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to indicate that this other question contains the solution. (To avoid multiple answers to the same issue floating around the site.) We usually do this by marking it as a duplicate but I can't do that at the moment :)

Comment: I don't think it is duplicated because I am not asking tiff. Using tiff to save it is one of the solutions.